# What are the easy to use and open source Baracode scanner for ios sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, open-source

I want to user barcode scanner in my app for ios in xcode 5.1, I want the barcode scanner to be Open-Source.
I googled but I couldn't find a good one.

Comment: Use ZBar bar code reader

Comment: I took a look on their description and it very old. they wrote it works only on iPhone 3Gs and 4

Comment: By the way, I'm using it in iPhone 5c as well as in 5s.

Comment: ah does it work well for all kinds of Baracode @Chan ?

Comment: Yes.. Its working. Use ZBar scanner :)

Comment: thank you so much. I will start with it right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ZBar bar code reader SDK. This is an open source for scanning.

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/

They have mentioned this is not working in iPhone 3G. But it works fine in iPhone 4 & above. I checked it as i'm using this SDK.

Comment: it works well...and this is article to make it works for 65-bit   http://www.federicocappelli.net/2012/10/05/zbar-library-for-iphone-5-armv7s/